# Intuition behind the extected value formula, for continuous cases

Tags: probability, intuition, expected-value

I was thinking about the formula that gives us the expected value of a continuous random variable with pdf $f(x)$, that is

$$E[X]=\int_{a}^{b} xf(x)dx$$
How can this, intuitively, gives us the expected value of $X$? I can totally understand it in the discrete case, because it is analogous to just calculating the arithmetic mean.

But here? I am not sure, there isn't even a proper probability in this formula.

The only thought that can give me some idea is that $f(x)dx$ is the probability that $X$ is in the small range of width $dx$. After this thought, and considering the integral as an infinite summation, I can see the analogy with the discrete case.

However I am not certain this is the way to think about it. A more detailed, based on intuition, reasoning would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following Riemann sum with $\Delta=(b-a)/n$:
$$
S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^* f(x_i^*)\Delta,
$$
where $x_i^*\in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ and $x_i=a+i\Delta$. The term $f(x_i^*)\Delta$ is, approximately, the probability of $X\in [x_{i-1},x_i]$, and so, $S_n$ can be interpreted as an aprroximate average of $X$. As $n$ increases, this approximation becomes better, and in the limit,
$$
S_n\to \int_a^b xf(x)\,dx=\mathsf{E}X.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To be honest this makes sense, I just wasn't aware that you cna generalize the definition of the Riemann integral. What I mean is, I knew that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f((x_i) \Delta$, but I didnt think to do it your way. What I understand, and please correct me if I am wrong, is that you do it by considering $x^*_i f(x^*_i)$ to be your function and so the definition I gave still holds. Other than that, I get the rest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, the integrand is given by $x\mapsto xf(x)$ in this case.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot for the answer. I guess I must get used to the idea of thinking the definite integral as a summation hehe :)